# How many function calls are needed for $T(12)$?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, dynamic-programming

Suppose, a function $T(N)$ is defined as follows :

$T(N)=\begin{cases}
 & \text{ $0$ }\ ; N< 1 \\ 
 & \text{ $1$ }\ ; N= 1 \\ 
 & \text{ $T(N-2) + T(N-3)$ }\ ; N> 1 
\end{cases}$

Then, $T(N)$ = ?

Answer (score 1):

To compute $T(12)$, the values of $T(10),T(9),\ldots,T(1),T(0),T(-1)$ will need to be computed, and no others.